# when i run my code, the output on "room number" will be just null and nothing else

Tags: c

```
void addadmin() {
FILE *f;
int menu;
int total;

int hargaTriple     = 3000000;
int hargaDoubleBed  = 2000000;
int hargaTwin       = 1500000;
int hargaSingleBed  = 1000000;

int a=0;
int i=0;
time_t t;
time(&t);

char test;
f=fopen("add.txt","a+");
if(f==0) {
    f=fopen("add.txt","w+");
    system("cls");
    printf("Please hold on while we set our database in your computer!!");
    printf("\n Process completed press any key to continue!!! ");
    getch();
}
while(1) {
    system("cls");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("-");
        printf("\n Current date and time : %s",ctime(&t));
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("-");
        printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("=");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t|ROOM RESERVATION|\t\t\t\t\t\n");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("=");
        printf("\n");
    
    printf("\n NAME         : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s.name,20);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n GENDER [M/F]     : ");
    scanf_s("%s", s.gender, 2);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n AGE          : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &s.age);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n ADDRESS      : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s.address);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n PHONE NUMBER     : ");
    scanf("%s",s.phonenumber);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n NATIONALITY      : ");
    scanf("%s",s.nationality);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n E-MAIL ADDRESS       : ");
    scanf(" %s",s.email);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n ROOM TYPE:");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter 1 -> EXECUTIVE TRIPLE");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter 2 -> DOUBLE ROOM");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter 3 -> TWIN ROOM");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter 4 -> SINGLE ROOM");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n Enter your choice: ");
    scanf_s("%s", s.typeroom, 10);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n NUMBER OF ROOM       : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &s.numberofroom);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    for(a=0; a<s.numberofroom; a++)
        printf("\n ROOM NUMBER      : %s",s.roomnumber[a]);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n PERIOD [DAYS]        : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &s.period);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n ARRIVAL [DD/MM/YYYY] : ");
        scanf("%s",&s.arrivaldate);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("=");
        printf("\n");
    printf("\n\n ROOM BOOKING DATA:");
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n NAME         : %s", s.name);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n GENDER           : %s", s.gender);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n AGE          : %d", s.age);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n ADDRESS      : %s",s.address);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n PHONE NUMBER     : %s",s.phonenumber);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n NATIONALITY      : %s",s.nationality);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n E-MAIL ADDRESS       : %s",s.email);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
    for(a=0; a<s.numberofroom; a++)
        printf("\n ROOM NUMBER      : %s",s.roomnumber[a]);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n ROOM TYPE        : %s", s.typeroom);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n NUMBER OF ROOM       : %d", s.numberofroom);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n PERIOD           : %d", s.period);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n ARRIVAL      : %s",&s.arrivaldate);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------");
```

I've tried to change roomnumber to numberofrooms but the output is just repetitive room number. The roomnumber was supposed to contain the room numbers but from what I understand, the roomnumber array is just a blank/empty array. So, how to change the output from null to number of rooms that i wanted?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  You posted dozens of lines of irrelevant code, while omitting the very important code showing how `s.roomnumber[a]` was defined and initialized.  (Maybe you're just forgetting to initialize it at all; I see no code reading it from the file.)  Ideally you would provide code that doesn't do file I/O, but if you must do file I/O you should provide a minimal input file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is a distinct lack of curly-braces for your for-loops

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, so it might not remove the previous newline as intended, so `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s.name,20);` needs a space before the first `%`, and the last argument `20` is invalid too. `scanf` isn't `scanf_s` but you have freely mixed their usage, so it will be very easy to get confused about the arguments they take.

Comment: Your structure `s` is not defined in the code you posted so it's difficult to see why `roomnumber[a]` would be empty.  But as far as I can tell, you are not setting `roomnumber[a]` to anything in *your posted code.*

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The indentation is tricking you, but I think all the for loops are *correct*

Comment: @ChristianGibbons - I agree. Always use braces - do not wish to get caught with your trousers down